# Swapping Views in Mac application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am creating an app in which I am able to swap the views using the top buttons named "1"and "2"....using them i can swap the views in the box. I am using the view controller. but the problem is that I want to swap my views using the buttons inside the view. I want to swap the view when I press the button inside one view. I have tried all the thing but not working.     [box setContentView:v];
    [box addSubview:v];
Please help
[image]

Comment: Please paste the source code that isn’t working.

Comment: Did you get this working as I am having the same issue?

Comment: yes i was able to solve that using the view controller or use BOx

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [NSView replaceSubview: with:];

Comment: yes I have tried that but its is not working. The two views are two different classes. I am sending the view number to the main class when clicking but not working.

Answer (score 0):

For button '1' action...

```
//For opening the second nib on first button click
NSWindowController * second=[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"secondNIB"];
[second showWindow:self];

//For closing the first nib, optional
//firstWindow is NSWindow
[firstWindow orderOut:nil];
```

For button '2' action...

```
//For opening the first nib on second button click
NSWindowController * first=[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"firstNIB"];
[first showWindow:self];

//For closing the second nib, optional
//secondWindow is NSWindow
[secondWindow orderOut:nil];
```

Comment: Your answer describes how to show and close windows while the OP is asking about view swapping.

Comment: Yes I want to change views ie NSView swapping. I am not using the Window controller.